# Intersect in R - miss one polygon

Tags: r, dataframe, spatial, intersect

**1. The problem**

I'm trying to extract the intersection of two polygons shapes in R. The first is the watershed polygon "ws_polygon_2", and the second is the Voronoi polygons of 5 rain gauges which was constructed from the Excel sheet "DATA.xlsx", both available here: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZntdYb5Eoiksy0v8BTlVFm7jewnscAx9).

The code is the following:

```
#[1] Montagem da tabela de coordenadas dos postos pluviométricos
library(sp)
library(readxl)
dados_precipitacao_1985 <- read_excel(path="C:/Users/.../DATA.xlsx") 
coordinates(dados_precipitacao_1985) <- ~ x + y 
proj4string(dados_precipitacao_1985) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") 
d_prec <- spTransform(dados_precipitacao_1985, CRSobj = "+init=epsg:3857") 

#[2] Coleta dos dados espaciais da bacia hidrográfica
library(rgdal)
bacia_Caio_Prado <- readOGR(dsn="C:/Users/...", layer="ws_polygon_2")
bacia_WGS <- spTransform(bacia_Caio_Prado, CRSobj = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
bacia_UTM <- spTransform(bacia_Caio_Prado, CRSobj = "+init=epsg:3857")

#[3] Poligonos de Thiessen - 1 INTERPOLAÇÃO
library(dismo)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
library(mapview)
limits_voronoi_WGS <- c(-40.00,-38.90,-5.00,-4.50)
v_WGS <- voronoi(dados_precipitacao_1985, ext=limits_voronoi_WGS)
bc <- aggregate(bacia_WGS)
u_WGS_1 <- gIntersection(spgeom1 = v_WGS, spgeom2 = bc,byid=TRUE)
u_WGS_2 <- intersect(bc, v_WGS)
```

When I apply the `intersect` function, the variable returned `u_WGS_2` is a spatial polygon data frame with only 4 features, instead of 5. The Voronoi object `v_WGS` has 5 features as well.

By other hand, when I apply the `gIntesection` function, I get 5 features. However, the `u_WGS_1` object is a spatial polygon only and I loss the rainfall data.

I'd like to know if I am committing any mistake or if there is any way to get the 5 features aggregated with the rainfall data in a spatial polygon data frame through the `intersect` function.

My objective is to transform this spatial polygon data frame with the rainfall data for each Voronoi polygon in a raster through the `rasterize` function later to compare with other interpolating results and satellite data.

Look these results. The first one is when I get the SPDF (Spatial Polygon Data Frame) I want, but missing the 5º feature. The second is the one I get with all the features I want, but missing the rainfall data.
[`spplot(u_WGS_2, 'JAN')`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CalyR.png)
[`plot(u_WGS_1)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7hZm.png)

**2. What I've tried**

1. I look into the `ws_polygon_2` shape searching for any other unwanted polygon who would pollute the shape and guide to this results. *The shape is composed by only one polygon feature, the correct watershed feature.*
2. I tried to use the `aggregate` function, as above, and as I saw in [this](http://rspatial.org/analysis/rst/4-interpolation.html) tutorial. *But I got the same result.*
3. I tried to create a SPDF with de `u_WGS_1` and the `d_prec`Spatial Point Data Frame object. *Actually, I'm working on it. And if it is the correct answer to my trouble, please help me with some code.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing polygon is removed because it is invalid

```
library(raster)
bacia <- shapefile("SHAPE_CORRIGIDO/ws_polygon_2.shp")
rgeos::gIsValid(bacia)

#[1] FALSE
#Warning message:
#In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
#  Ring Self-intersection at or near point -39.070555560000003 -4.8419444399999998
```

The self-intersection is here:

```
zoom(bacia, ext=extent(-39.07828, -39.06074, -4.85128, -4.83396))
points(cbind( -39.070555560000003, -4.8419444399999998))
```

Invalid polygons are removed as they are assumed to have been produced by intersect. In this case, the invalid data was already there and should have been retained. I will see if I can fix that.

Comment: Well noted. Please, tell us if you discover anything about it.

Comment: Robert, I've searched the self intersection and I found it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cw9OCs7RC4abnFQUpm1G9aFqFdgE3W2C). When I edited it manually, the script runs well and I get the correct answer I wanted, [look](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pnwsZLWoKTP75TrH3WXesfOINzOWIBgX). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue when using `st_intersection()` from **sf**, which retains the data from both data sets. Mind that `dismo::voronoi()` is compatible with **sp** objects only, so the precipitation data needs to be available in that format, at least temporarily. If you do not feel comfortable with **sf** and prefer to continue working with Spatial* objects after the actual intersection, simply invoke the `as()` method upon the output **sf** object as shown below.

```
library(sf)

#[1] Montagem da tabela de coordenadas dos postos pluviométricos
dados_precipitacao_1985 <- readxl::read_excel(path="data/DATA.xlsx") 
dados_precipitacao_1985 <- st_as_sf(dados_precipitacao_1985, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)
dados_precipitacao_1985_sp <- as(dados_precipitacao_1985, "Spatial")

#[2] Coleta dos dados espaciais da bacia hidrográfica
bacia_Caio_Prado <- st_read(dsn="data/SHAPE_CORRIGIDO", layer="ws_polygon_2")

#[3] Poligonos de Thiessen - 1 INTERPOLAÇÃO
limits_voronoi_WGS <- c(-40.00,-38.90,-5.00,-4.50)
v_WGS <- dismo::voronoi(dados_precipitacao_1985_sp, ext=limits_voronoi_WGS)
v_WGS_sf <- st_as_sf(v_WGS)

u_WGS_3 <- st_intersection(bacia_Caio_Prado, v_WGS_sf)
plot(u_WGS_3[, 6], key.pos = 1)
```

[image: precip-january]